# Sourcing another user profile exits my own script

Tags: shell, ksh

I am working on a script on a ksh shell that should source another user's profile in the middle of it.

For example:
myscript.sh contains:

```
echo 'something'       ## appears in the output         
. /someuser/.profile   ## profile not sourced
echo 'another'         ## Does not appear
```

After running the script, it returns just the 'something' keyword, refuses sourcing the profile, and neglect anything after the sourcing command.

But when I run those commands separately (not in a script), the profile returns some errors but it is sourced fine and I can run the other commands successfully! Why that happens? Could it be something in that profile itself?

Comment: Are you using `set -e` aka errexit aka `ksh -e`?

Comment: No, those are not used in the .profile file

Comment: Are they used in your script?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of your script and watch what it prints out just before it exits.